# Find text in file and set it as a variable. Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I try to find one line in whole text file. Next I need to set this line as a variable.

When I try do this:

```
set MY_VARIABLE=findstr /I "MY_TEXT" MY.FILE
echo %MY_VARIABLE%
```

The result of `echo` is `findstr /I "MY_TEXT" MY.FILE`, but I want to see result of this command line instead.

When I try do this – first enter in `cmd`:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "MY_TEXT" MY.FILE') do set "batToolDir=%%a"
```

then enter in `cmd`:

```
echo "%batToolDir%"
```

I see an error:

> ```
> the %%a variable is unsuspected
> ```

When I make a file `SCRIPT.bat`:

```
@echo off 
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('set MY_VARIABLE=findstr /I "MY_TEXT" MY.FILE') do set "batToolDir=%%a"
echo "%batToolDir%"
```

I get this:

> ```
> ""
> ```

What is wrong? How to make this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost done

For command line

```
for /F "delims=" %a in ('findstr /I "MY_TEXT" MY.FILE') do set "batToolDir=%a"
```

For batch file double the percent signs

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "MY_TEXT" MY.FILE') do set "batToolDir=%%a"
```