# How to read whats in a .dat file in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch script which auto deletes `Fortnite` and I need to get the install location of it, which is specific for every user.

This install location is located in line `4` of `C:\ProgramData\Epic\UnrealEngineLauncher\LauncherInstalled.dat`.

It says:

```
"InstallLocation": "D:\Low programs\Fortnite\Fortnite",
```

How do I get my batch script to read the location above so it can delete it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text in file and set it as a variable. Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198458/find-text-in-file-and-set-it-as-a-variable-batch-file)

Comment: Please clarify: Is there really a comma at the end of the line? And are those really double `\\\`?

Answer (score 0):

use `findstr` to filter your data file down to the needed line and capture the relevant part of that line with a `for /f`:

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=3delims^=^" %%a in ('type "C:\ProgramData\Epic\UnrealEngineLauncher\LauncherInstalled.dat"^|findstr /c:"\"InstallLocation\":"') do set "location=%%b"
ECHO del "%location%"
```

NOTE: remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting, when the code does what you want.

Comment: Hey i'm new and i can't get it to work with my file which is located in `C:\ProgramData\Epic\UnrealEngineLauncher\LauncherInstalled.dat`

Comment: Is that better now?

Comment: can you comment again what you commented? sorry i somehow can't see your comment.

Comment: if there really is a comma (what I doubt until confirmed by Narrow), @LotPings is right, but `"tokens=1*delims=: ,"` wouldn't work either. In that case, I would switch to `for /f tokens^=3delims^=^" %%a ...` (as ugly a it looks...)

Comment: where in the command do i input my file location? And yes. there is a comma in the .dat file. And no. normal \